# Firebug not showing ::before and ::after pseudo-elements

Tags: firebug, pseudo-element

After searching extensively on why these pseudo-elements are not shown by Firebug in the HTML inspector the way they are in the Firefox and Chrome built-in debugger, I came across a number of results indicating that this is indeed possible. But testing on 4 different computers including Windows and Mac OS I still could not find these in the HTML inspector. Is there some setting I am missing?

Right now I am using Firefox 38.0.5 and Firebug 2.0.11 on Mac Yosemite.

Update:

Actually it looks like this feature is still in development: https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5785. The screenshots I saw must have been related to that effort.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug displays pseudo-elements within the [*Style* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel) for the selected element, not within the main HTML panel.

[image: <code>::before</code> pseudo-element shown in *Style* side panel]

Comment: I am using v42 - no idea where these are now, since the side-panel has a completely different set of options - none of which display "after" styling.  I will revert to an older version until I can get this much better set of choices.

Comment: Because Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/), you should give the Firefox DevTools a try, which even show the [pseudo-elements within the node view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML#before_and_after) in their Inspector. Having said that, Firefox 42 is very much outdated at this point of time, so I suggest to update your browser.